# How to remove the timestamp from the filename?

Tags: excel, vbscript, scripting, vba

Hi I'm writing a script to rename and move the generated files to a folder.  The file name of the generated files has the time stamp appended at the end of it.

> Eg: Apache34-22-09.bak
>       Tomcat44-26-06.bak

I would like to remove the time stamp from the file name like the below.

> Eg: Apache.bak
>       Tomcat.bak

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I would like to remove the time stamp from the file name like the below.` So what is stopping you?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, Taking **Apache34-22-09.bak** as example.  I would like to remove **'34-22-09'** from the file name.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @SiddharthRout This is what I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For Each fil In fol.Files sName = Left(fil.Name, (Len(fil.Name) - 8)) fil.Name = sName Next – arunpandiyarajhen 2 mins ago

This will work with extensions like `.xlsx` as well. The below code doesn't hard code the extension.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim NewFname  as String

    fileName = "Apache34-22-09.bak"

    '~~> Get File name without the extension
    Fname = Left(fileName, (InStrRev(fileName, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))

    '~~> Create the new file name
    NewFname = Left(Fname, Len(Fname) - 8) & Replace(fileName, Fname, "")

    Debug.Print NewFname
End Sub
```

Comment: @arunpandiyarajhen: I had the code ready 34 minutes ago :) If you would have shown efforts to solve it yourself, I would have answered it then. For your future reference, always include in your question what you tried and where are you stuck :)

Comment: Sure Siddharth. I would do that.  Actually, I'm very new to vbscript.  I've almost reached my requirement. I've got stuck in this time stamp alone. I would mail you my entire code and requirement. Please give your mail id.

Comment: @arunpandiyarajhen: Sorry but I don't help people on emails and if I do then I charge them :D If you get stuck, simply post a question here in stackoverflow with the code that you tried and indicate the portion where you are stuck and someone will definitely help you :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout what if the file name is dynamic and still holds a date. How to remove it? Say it can have data either at the start or end of file name? Eg ddmmyyyyFilename.txt ot Filenameddmmyyyy.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code piece:

Left(fileName, (Len(fileName) - 12)) & ".bak"

It should be like this, try and see.

Comment: Basically, it returns a specified number of characters from the left side of a string until the point that date begins.

Comment: Then, you can rename the file with this returned string value.

Comment: Have you tested it before posting? :)

Comment: Of course, no I just tried to give an approach about how to do that, but I am sure it is correct.

Comment: `but I am sure it is correct.` You might want to check it again :)

Comment: For Each fil In fol.Files
 sName = Left(fil.Name, (Len(fil.Name) - 8))
 fil.Name = sName
Next

Comment: Ok, you are right, now I have tested it and it should definitely be like following:

Left(fileName, (Len(fileName) - 12)) & ".bak"

Comment: Please see my comment above.

Comment: You can test it too

Left(fileName, (Len(fileName) - 12)) & ".bak"

Comment: What are you saying in previous post? Could you elaborate it more? You asked how to remove date info from the filename, and I gave the correct code to do that, now you are using loop.

Comment: should always make code as generic as possible (like Siddharth had done), your code will only work with 3 character extension. It will not get it right if the extension changed to something like `.7z`, `.backup`, etc.

Comment: I know that very well but I just immediately replied his question, that's why I wrote it for a specific purpose.